# I don't understand the meaning of this code, Can you help me?

Tags: linux, awk

```
awk '/\$1|\$6/{print $1}' /etc/shadow   
awk '/$1|$6/{print $1}' /etc/shadow
```

Chinese version

```
awk '/$1|$6/{print $1}' /etc/shadow 查询远程登录的用户信息
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hdvtY.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The <dollar-sign> operator in awk is used to reference fields. An expression like `$expr` references the field number returned by `expr`. So the action `{print $1}` will print the first field. (See [awk POSIX standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html))

When used in an extended regular expression, the <dollar-sign> loses its meaning as an awk-operator and is used as an anchor to the end of the string. (See [Regular Expressions POSIX standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_04))

- `ef$` will match the string `abcdef` but not the string `abcdefgh`
- `ef$g` will never match anything as it fails to match `g` after the end.

Again, the <dollar-sign> loses its meaning in a regular expression when escaped as `\$`. This and the above rules clearly make a distinction between `/\$1|\$6/` and `/$1|$6/` in the OP's awk examples:

- `/\$1|\$6/` will match `$1` or `$6`
- `/$1|$6/` will never match anything

`/etc/shadow` is a file which contains the password information for the system's accounts and optional ageing information. Each line of this file contains 9 fields, separated by colons (`:`). Where the first field represents the user name, the second field is of interest here. The second field contains the encrypted password in the following format (<dollar-sign> separated):

```
$id$salt$encrypted
```

Here `$id` tells you which encryption is used for the password:

> ```
> ID  | Method
> ─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
> 1   | MD5
> 2a  | Blowfish (not in mainline glibc; added in some
>     | Linux distributions)
> 5   | SHA-256 (since glibc 2.7)
> 6   | SHA-512 (since glibc 2.7)
> ```
>
> **<sub>source: `man crypt 3` and `man shadow 5`</sub>**

So in essence, the awk line

```
awk '/\$1|\$6/{print $1}' /etc/shadow
```

will search for accounts that are MD5 or SHA-512 encoded.

There is however a problem with the line. The characters in `salt` and `encrypted` are drawn from the set `[a–zA–Z0–9./]`. This implies that `$1` or `$6` can be encountered in the string if `salt` starts with `1` or `6` (ditto for `encrypted`). The line should read:

```
awk -F:  '$2 ~ /^\$[1,6]/{print $1}' /etc/shadow
```

**More information about this on:**

- `man shadow 5`
- `man crypt 3`
- https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/understanding-etcshadow-file/

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. From your answer, I understand the meaning of this code. You are really great!